# how to convert php file into csv

Tags: php, csv

```
$lang['add_a']="Add a";
$lang['ban_zon_link']="Banner, Zone linking";
$lang['ban_zon_link_help']="Zones linking with Banners";
$lang['manage_ban_zon_link_help']="Manage banner zone linking -";
$lang['adtag']="Ad Tag";
```

I saved above lines into php file as lang.php need to convert php file into csv in code level.

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: for example $lang['add_a']  as first column     = as second column     "Add a";=as third column

Comment: I guess you want to export the PHP array `$lang` in CSV format or what do you mean with PHP file into CSV?

Comment: for example $lang['add_a'] as first column  = as second column    "Add a"; as third column

Answer (score 0):

You could open the file as csv,  iterate over your array and use  fputcsv

```
foreach($lang as $myrow) {
    fputcsv($output, $myrow);
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Answer (score 0):

```
include("lang.php");
foreach($lang as $l)
{
    file_put_contents("csv_file.csv",$l.",",FILE_APPEND);
    // csv_file.csv is the name of your file
}
file_put_contents("csv_file.csv","\n",FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: i have saved files as php

Comment: php closing added only

Answer (score 0):

You can use fputcsv:

```
<?php
$lang = ...
$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

// Insert array keys as CSV header
fputcsv($fp, array_keys($lang);

// Insert values as first data row
fputcsv($fp, array_values($fields));

fclose($fp);
?>
```

This works if you have only row record in your $lang array as your example suggests. This will create a 2 rows CSV with an header (the keys of the $lang array) and one data row (the values of the array.

If you are aiming at a different thing please clarify your question.

Comment: $fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');my file is  not csv ,its a  php file needto convert csv

Answer (score 0):

try with this:-

```
/*    $lang['add_a']="Add a";
    $lang['ban_zon_link']="Banner, Zone linking";
    $lang['ban_zon_link_help']="Zones linking with Banners";
    $lang['manage_ban_zon_link_help']="Manage banner zone linking -";
    $lang['adtag']="Ad Tag";*/
```

if above php code in lang.php:-

```
 require_once "lang.php";

 $fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
    fputcsv($fp, array_keys($lang));
    fputcsv($fp, array_values($lang));
    fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

To read in a PHP script and write it out, I've done the following...

```
<?php
$file="part1.php";
$outFile="part1.csv";
$in = file($file);
$out = fopen($outFile, "w");

foreach($in as $line )  {
    $parts = explode("=", $line);
    if ( count($parts) == 2 )   {
        fputcsv($out, array($parts[0],"=",rtrim($parts[1],";".PHP_EOL)));
    }
}
fclose($out);
```

which for your example ( as part1.php) gives...

```
$lang['add_a'],=,"""Add a"""
$lang['ban_zon_link'],=,"""Banner, Zone linking"""
$lang['ban_zon_link_help'],=,"""Zones linking with Banners"""
$lang['manage_ban_zon_link_help'],=,"""Manage banner zone linking -"""
$lang['adtag'],=,"""Ad Tag"""
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $file = 'file.csv';
 header( "Content-Type: text/csv;charset=utf-8" );
 header( "Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"$file\"" );
 header("Pragma: no-cache");
 header("Expires: 0");
 $fp= fopen('php://output', 'w');
 foreach ($lang as $fields) 
 {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
 }
 fclose($fp);
 exit();
```